# Run KernelEvents::REQUEST event before hook_node_access?

Tags: 8, event-subscribers

I'm doing some central static variable setup for the request and was hoping to use `KernelEvents::REQUEST` to run first and set the variables.

However, I've found that while the documentation states:

> The REQUEST event occurs at the very beginning of request dispatching.

`hook_node_access` actually runs before the `KernelEvents::REQUEST` event handler:

```
  /**
   * The subscribed events.
   */
  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    $events = [];
    $events[KernelEvents::REQUEST][] = ['onKernelRequest', 1];
    return $events;
  }
```

then in the event listener:

```
  public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event) {
    drupal_set_message(__FUNCTION__ . ': ' . microtime());
  }
```

and in `hook_node_access`

then in the event listener:

```
  public function mymodule_node_accesss(NodeInterface $node, $op, AccountInterface $account) {
    drupal_set_message(__FUNCTION__ . ': ' . microtime());
  }
```

Output:

```
mymodule_node_access: 0.76379200 1518995630
onKernelRequest: 0.77758400 1518995630
```

As we can see from microtime order, `hook_node_access` runs first. Anyway to make it run after the `KernelEvents::REQUEST` event handler? thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, after a bit more digging, I found the solution.

The "weight" param for `['onKernelRequest', 1]` is sort DESC, so the higher weight number will run first.

Adjusting the event listener with weight `1000` as follows means it runs before the `hook_node_access` invoking listener

```
  /**
   * The subscribed events.
   */
  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    $events = [];
    $events[KernelEvents::REQUEST][] = ['onKernelRequest', 1000];
    return $events;
  }
```

Comment: That is because weight  is not a weight, it is a priority. The higher the value, the more important it is. This is coming directly from Symfony, that's why it is different to how weights in Drupal typically work. The access check happens as part of routing, which is priority 32, see \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::getSubscribedEvents. Instead of 1000, you might want to use something just slightly higher than that, because 1000 also runs before authentication (300) and other things that you might rely on